# Bundle in a fragment created

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there anyway to assign a Bundle to a fragment already created?. I tried something like this:

```
Bundle mArgumentos = new Bundle();
mArgumentos.putString("id", id);
this.setArguments(mArgumentos);
```

But I get the error: Fragment already active.

I'm just wondering if I can achieve this without overriding the onBackPressed() method.

My purpose with this is because I have a form for registry a new item. From here I can go to another fragment (lets call it fragment_B) with the new id of the item (I call fragment_B with a bundle assigning the new id). When the user presses back button, he gets to the previous form but the id is missing (this is because the form goes to the previous state, like empty), so if he tries to go to fragment_B again, he cant because the id.

Obviously the user cant go to  fragment_B if the form has not been save. So the user saves the form and then press the button to go to fragment_B with its new id:

```
FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();

Bundle mArgumentos = new Bundle();
mArgumentos.putString("id",id);

fragment.setArguments(mArgumentos);

FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, tag);
ft.addToBackStack(tag);
ft.commit();
```

Any suggestions?.

**Edit:**
[image]

The fragments are not in the same activity. When I create a new item and press button save I should be in a "edit mode". This means that after I create the item I can come back and edit it. I'm just using the same fragment to edit and create. So, when I create the item, press the button to go to fragment_B and then press back button, I should be like "edit mode" of this item. This means that from fragment_B to the previous I should pass the id of the item created. That's why I wanna know if I can do this without overriding the onBackpress method.

**Edit2:**

If there is no other way to achieve this, I was thinking in override the onBackpress method like this:

```
//get the fragment where I'm staying on.
Fragment fragmentActual = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.tabcontent);

//get the tag of the fragment
String fragmentTag = fragmentActual.getTag().toString();

if (fragmentTag.equals("tagFragmentB")){
    Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();

Bundle mArguments = fragmentActual.getArguments();
String id = mArguments.getString("id");

    if(id != null){

        fragmentA .setArguments(mArguments);

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, "fragmentA");
        ft.addToBackStack("fragmentA");
        ft.commit();
    }

}else{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

This is working but as you have notice, this change the order of the fragments called by the user and this should be invisible for the user. So, this forces me to put more code in order to get the calls that the user did.

I'm kind of new with this, so maybe I have not the "Android thinking". If is there a better way to do what I want, I'm open to everything. I just want to do the thinks right and dont have problems in the future just because a user pressed a back button.

Comment: You didn't provide a full set of details about what you're doing so(like are those fragments in the same activity): *Is there anyway to assign a Bundle to a fragment already created?* - no. First of all, is the user supposed to get back to the form? You have a form to register a new item and you pass that to another fragment with the id. But if you get back to the form isn't the form supposed to make a new item(so why the need to go to the fragment b with the old id)? And after you get to the form(from fragment b) how do you go again to fragment b?

Comment: Followup: If you follow the same steps like when creating a new item then you didn't quite think this through. If you allow the form to edit the newly created fragment b on a back button press then the form fragment should be able to see the new fragment and retrieve its data without needing the explicit id. After you sort this things out, I would go with making the fragments communicate  with the parent activity(and pass the id between them) and let it sort out the id storage and use.

Comment: hi Luksprog thanks for the help again ;). I just edited my question.

Comment: "After you sort this things out, I would go with making the fragments communicate with the parent activity(and pass the id between them) and let it sort out the id storage and use". How do I should do this?

Comment: Can't you simply use the `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstance()` method for the activity that holds the new form fragment to store the id(and any data from that form)?

Comment: I havent use those methods before, but I'll do a research about them. I'll let you know if I made it work. Thanks :)

Comment: What about `setRetainInstance()` for fragment A?

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is never called when I press back button from fragmentB. This method is called when I change the orientation of my device for example. I'll do a research about setRetainInstance.

Comment: when I press back button the information on my form is retain, but I cant access to its content, I mean I tried etIdHidden.getText().toString(); in onCreateView But it returns empty. Do you guys know why?. I was trying to keep the id in an editText hidden, because the information is filled when back button is pressed, but I cant get info. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in my particular situation a made it work doing the following: I noticed that when I fill the form, saved it, then go to fragmentB and finally press back button, the information of my form was retained. So I put a hidden etidText in my form:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textEditHiddenId"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

When the button save is pressed, I set the content of this editText:

```
etIdHidden.setText(id);
```

When the activity is created, according to http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html, the method onResume is called after the onCreateView. So, I get the value of my textEditHiddenId in this method:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String id= etIdHidden.getText().toString();

    if(id.equals("")==false){
        mArgumentos=new Bundle();
        mArgumentos.putString("id", ""+id);

    }

};
```

The first time, the content of textEditHiddenId is empty, but when backbutton is pressed and the onResume method is called, I get the content initialized and I can override my Bundle.

Simplest solution ever..